# How do differentiate between function arguments and multiplication?

Tags: notation

Say I have the following:
$$ H\left(\frac x{x_o}\right) $$

How do I see that it is the $H$ function at $x/x_0$ and not the quantifty $H_n$ premultiplied by $x/x_0$?

In Mathematica, I would have `H[x/x0]` and `H(x/x0)` respectively. And in C, I would have `H(x/x_0)` and `H*(x/x_0)`

Is there some way to clarify this in LaTeX code, say with less spacing between $H$ and the parenteses with `\!`?

Comment: I guess you only need to define your notations clearly in the beginning. If you do so you should really never be in such an ambiguous state ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will generally be contextually clear. For example, if $H$ isn't a function, or if $H$ is a function but $\frac x{x_0}$ isn't in its domain, then it's (almost) certainly meant to represent multiplication. In the case that $H$ is a function and it could make sense to talk about multiplication by $\frac{x}{x_0}$ instead of evaluation at $\frac{x}{x_0}$, we will generally use the expression in your post to indicate evaluation, and (some variation on) one of the following to indicate multiplication:

$$\frac{x}{x_0}H$$

$$\frac x{x_0}\cdot H$$

$$H\cdot\frac x{x_0}$$